# How do I see what the current "scope" is in SublimeText?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I'm trying to define some snippets for editing Markdown, but I can't get them to trigger. I have tried using `source.markdown`, `text.markdown` and `markdown` as the scope, but none of them work. If I *remove* the scope constraint, the snippet works.

How do I figure out what scope to use?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To determine the current scope under your cursor, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows and Linux does the trick, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on a Mac.

Alternatively, run the following in the Sublime console:

```py
view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].begin())
```

To bring up the console on Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>

Comment: Marking this as accepted as it's technically a better answer (doesn't require a plugin)

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P works on Linux as well.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + P won't work for me in Linux Ubuntu 20.04 for some reason, so I created a custom keyboard shortcut to Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S, and that works fine now. See my question here: [Ctrl + Alt + Shift + P doesn't work to "Show Scope Name" in Sublime Text 4 in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1711933/425838)

Answer (score 2):

The scope for Markdown is `text.html.markdown`. I think there are several packages that help you identify the current scope, [ScopeAlways](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeAlways) is one of them.

Comment: Nice, that worked! I'm confused though. If `text.html.markdown` works, shouldn't just `markdown` work too? I guess the scopes don't work the way I thought they did.

Comment: ScopeAlways works flawlessly by the way, couldn't ask for more.

Comment: The scope gets more specific with each appended child. Snippets in the scope `text` will work for all child scopes, e.g. `text.html` and `text.html.markdown`, but the latter will not work in any of its parents. You can also exclude certain child scopes, e.g. `text.html -text.html.markdown`.

Comment: I thought it got more specific for each *prepended* child. Thanks for explaining :)